# JSF what is the component source of the request?

Tags: java, jsf, trinidad

I'm using Trinidad Library.

I have `commandButton` that has `partialSubmit=true` attribute and a panel that has `partialTriggers` that point to that `commandButton`.

How can I know on the server side what is the source of the request , I mean which component fire the partial trigger?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The information is in the request parameters map.

I took the requestParameterMap out of the ExternaContext and one of the attribute in the map was the source of the request. this can give you the form that sumbit this request.

Answer (score 0):

You have a command button like this:

```
<tr:commandButton styleClass="formbutton"
    id="yourId"
    partialSubmit="true" 
    textAndAccessKey="&YourText" 
    actionListener="#{yourBean.yourAction}">
</tr:commandButton>
```

and a managed bean with such a function:

```
public void yourAction(ActionEvent event)
   {
       event.getComponent().getId();
   }
```

Comment: I solved the issue.
The information appear in request Parameters.

Comment: @johnSmith please post an answer with the current solution and mark the post as an answer.